# Counting Total Child Nodes in Titan GraphDB through Gremlin Query

Tags: java-8, gremlin, graph-databases, titan, child-nodes

I had created [Titan Graph](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/javadoc/current/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanGraph.html) of hierarchical tree in Java. 
How do you find total child nodes hierarchy from a specified node with [Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html)?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mre]". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? What is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic pattern for traversing a tree lies in [repeat()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step) step. As an example, I use the graph depicted in the [Tree Recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#tree) section of the TinkerPop documentation:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV(id, 'A').as('a').
......1>            addV(id, 'B').as('b').
......2>            addV(id, 'C').as('c').
......3>            addV(id, 'D').as('d').
......4>            addV(id, 'E').as('e').
......5>            addV(id, 'F').as('f').
......6>            addV(id, 'G').as('g').
......7>            addE('hasParent').from('a').to('b').
......8>            addE('hasParent').from('b').to('c').
......9>            addE('hasParent').from('d').to('c').
.....10>            addE('hasParent').from('c').to('e').
.....11>            addE('hasParent').from('e').to('f').
.....12>            addE('hasParent').from('g').to('f').iterate()
gremlin> g.V('F').repeat(__.in('hasParent')).emit().count()
==>6
gremlin> g.V('C').repeat(__.in('hasParent')).emit().count()
==>3
gremlin> g.V('A').repeat(__.in('hasParent')).emit().count()
==>0
```

The key to getting the count is in the use of `emit()` which allows all the traversers encountered in the `repeat()` to be counted.

Just for comparison to what kind of speed you can get with TinkerGraph (in-memory) I generated a 400,000 vertex deep tree:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> lastV = g.addV().next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> (0..<400000).each{lastV=g.V(lastV).as('f').addV().as('t').addE('next').from('f').to('t').select('t').next()}
==>0
==>1
==>2
==>3
...
gremlin> graph
==>tinkergraph[vertices:400001 edges:400000]
gremlin> clockWithResult{ g.V(0L).repeat(__.out('next')).emit().count().next() }
==>171.44102253
==>400000
```

Done in 171ms. TinkerGraph is obviously faster as it holds its data purely in-memory. Titan/JanusGraph and other graphs have to read from disk.

Comment: you are right.... i had done like that .... my question is how to fasten query execution of titan graph. i had done indexing properly. give me some suggestions for tree of total nodes up-to 4 lacs and its query execution takes time of 5-10 seconds only

Comment: its about 3.5 lacs of edges in titan-graph..... how to speed up the traversal queries?? please help me. give me some coding of java implementations

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything in Gremlin that can make this go faster. The traversal I wrote in my answer is about as optimal as it can be. Indices won't help you beyond looking up the root vertex that you start the traversal from, so there's not much in Titan's schema features that will help. If the data doesn't change often, you could obviously pre-compute the count and store it on the root vertex then update it periodically if something changes. I guess the problem is that in order to get the count you have to traverse to every vertex and there's no way around that.

Comment: would you give me java code for titangraph with dynamodb as a backend with complete indexing....i had trying titangraph(backend : cassandra) with  nodes up-to 4 lacs and it's takes time of 2 minutes to count total child nodes of root node.is it okey??

Comment: There's no real difference in TinkerPop 3.x between the Gremlin java and Gremlin groovy. My console code example is equally usable in a java application. It is hard to say if you traversal speed is expected exactly. It's going to be related to how wide.deep your tree is. You mentioned 4 million vertices - if you have to traverse a tree that counts tens of thousands of those or more then i could see that 2 minutes is probably expected. If your tree is not that deep/wide as in counting 100 vertices then 2 minutes sounds unreasonable.

Comment: And - again, indices won't help you in this case. They help with an initial lookup for the root vertex and that's it. If you didn't have that in in place on a 4 million vertex graph then i'd expect your traversal to be even slower than what you have now with 2 minutes. The code for running all this on dynamo or cassandra or whatever else titan supports should be basically the same. The connection configuration information is all that changes.

Comment: thank you. Is there anyway for implementing deeper tree that give the execution of query faster?? or should i drop that idea??

Comment: and there are not 4 million vertices.its 4 lacs means 400000 vertices.

Comment: Should i move to another graph database like Neo4j, ArangoDB, Blazegraph, orientDb etc. Is titanGraph slower ?? i m cofused...

Comment: Here's some general advice: Given 400000 vertices and assuming your data does not change you could probably just use TinkerGraph and hold all the data in-memory. If you need transactions and don't expect a lot of growth then Neo4j is fine. If you expect massive growth where you will have eventually have billions of vertices then you should stick with Titan/JanusGraph. If you stick with Titan/JanusGraph and your trees remain deep/wide then I think you may need to get clever with how you do this traversal (precomputation of the value may be one way to deal with it as mentioned earlier).

Comment: Note that you are also using TinkerPop - don't miss out on one of the best parts of using it - you can easily switch from one graph database to another. Try OrientDB or Neo4j or any of them - the Gremlin is still going to be the same for all of them. Also, if you use the Gremlin Console, you can quickly test right from there especially since your graph is small. I updated my answer with a quick benchmark of TinkerGraph. You can use the same script for all the others graph databases to get a rough test of speed.

Comment: my data has nature of changing.

Comment: FWIW, I ran Stephen's script on tinkergraph (141 ms), janusgraph inmemory (2138 ms), janusgraph berkeleyje (2912 ms), janusgraph cassandra single node (2534 ms).

Comment: give me your java code for titangraph with cassandra as backend.Does hardware configurations matter for speed of traversal

Comment: in Stephen's script , i want answer of g.V('C').repeat(__.out('hasParent')).emit().count() actually. i want reduce its execution time. vertex C is root of tree and there are 400000 nodes in tree.

Comment: The depth of the tree he tested is the same as the one I tested - 400000. He ran my script against all those different backends of JanusGraph (formerly Titan) - just as I suggested you try. I still suggest you try building your own personal benchmarks in the Gremlin Console to get a rough test of speed of different configurations and settings. It's exceedingly simple to do - a few lines of code. There is no one size fits all answer to graphs. You just need to test your own situation. As far as the Gremlin code goes, you can't write that in a more optimal manner.

Comment: I ran Cassandra single node on the same machine as the Gremlin Console. Use `bin/titan.sh start` to start the node. The configuration file is under `conf/titan-cassandra.properties`. http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html